# Register user while posting entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Rails 4 + devise.

Imagine we have some entity form. There are user fields name, email, password for not signed in users and few fields from entity (for signed in users there are no name/email/passwd fields). In other words, I need to combine two actions (register and post a question) in one. How can I solve this problem inside of backend (controller)?

[image]

UPD
Added some code from controller / views, but don't think it would be helpfull.

questions_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new unless user_signed_in?
    @question = Question.new

    render "new"
  end
end
```

new.html.slim

```
= form_for @question do |f| # Don't know how to combine form for user and question
  - unless user_signed_in?
    = text_field @user, :name
    = text_field @user, :email
    = text_field @user, :password
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.text_area :summary
```

Comment: Can you please put in some code. Controller and view.

Comment: Done, added code from controller and view.

Comment: Here you should pass user registration params along with question params and in controller if user is valid based on user_params then create question and then `sign_in` user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `QuestionsController` you can put some logic to create the user first then sign in with the created user. Finally handle the creation of the question.

```
def create
  # Permit the strong parameters as you're using rails 4
  params.require(:question).permit(:title, :summary)
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)

  logged_in = false #initialize a logged_in flag
  if user_signed_in?
    logged_in = true #set the flag to true if logged in.
  else
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in(@user) #sign in the user if the creation was a success
      logged_in = true #set the flag to true if the user created.
    end
  end

  if logged_in
    @question = current_user.questions.new(params[:question])

    if @question.save
      redirect_to questions_path #put in your logic after successful creation of question
    else
      render :new
    end
  else
    render :new
  end

end
```

You'd need to change the `new.html.slim` a bit to build the exact params we have used above.

```
= form_for @question do |f|
 - unless user_signed_in?
   = text_field :user, :name
   = text_field :user, :email
   = text_field :user, :password
 = f.text_field :title
 = f.text_area :summary
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rails nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to accept params.
Add nested attributes relation between User and Question models

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = current_user || User.new 
    @question = @user.questions.new

    render "new"
  end

  def create
    user_params = params['user']
    question_params = user_params.delete('questions_attributes')['0']
    @user = current_user || User.new(user_params)
    @question = @user.questions.new(question_params)
    if @user.valid? && @question.valid?
      @user.save && @question.save
      sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to :index
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end


= form_for @user do |user|
  - unless user_signed_in?
    = user.text_field :name
    = user.text_field :email
    = user.text_field :password
  = user.fields_for :questions do |question|
    = question.text_field :title
    = question.text_area :summary
```

Comment: How can I DRY it for all "new" actions?